# How can I efficiently generate a dataframe of simulated values?

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to generate a data frame of simulated values based on existing distribution parameters. My main data frame contains the mean and standard deviation for each observation, like so:

```
example.data <- data.frame(country=c("a", "b", "c"), 
                           score_mean=c(0.5, 0.4, 0.6), 
                           score_sd=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2))

#   country score_mean score_sd
# 1       a        0.5      0.1
# 2       b        0.4      0.1
# 3       c        0.6      0.2
```

I can use `sapply()` and a custom function to use the score_mean and score_sd parameters to randomly draw from a normal distribution:

```
score.simulate <- function(score.mean, score.sd) {
  return(mean(rnorm(100, mean=score.mean, sd=score.sd)))
}

simulated.scores <- sapply(example.data$score_mean, 
                       FUN=score.simulate, 
                       score.sd=example.data$score_sd)

# [1] 0.4936432 0.3753853 0.6267956
```

This will generate one round (or column) of simulated values. However, I'd like to generate a lot of columns (like 100 or 1,000). The only way I've found to do this is to wrap my `sapply()` function inside a generic function inside `lapply()` and then convert the resulting list into a data frame with `ldply()` in `plyr`:

```
results.list <- lapply(1:5, FUN=function(x) sapply(example.data$score_mean, FUN=score.simulate, score.sd=example.data$score_sd))

library(plyr)
simulated.scores <- as.data.frame(t(ldply(results.list)))

#           V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
# V1 0.5047807 0.4902808 0.4857900 0.5008957 0.4993375
# V2 0.3996402 0.4128029 0.3875678 0.4044486 0.3982045
# V3 0.6017469 0.6055446 0.6058766 0.5894703 0.5960403
```

This works, but (1) it seems really convoluted, especially with the `as.data.frame(t(ldply(lapply(... FUN=function(x) sapply ...))))` approach, (2) it is really slow when using large numbers of iterations or bigger data—my actual dataset has 3,000 rows, and running 1,000 iterations takes 1–2 minutes.

Is there a more efficient way to create a data frame of simulated values like this?

Comment: You might want to not take the values from an existing data frame, but rather take them from vectors.  Then create new vectors.  After that, then put them back into a data frame.  This way, R doesn't have to spend time searching through a data frame to get values.

Comment: So manually extract the columns of interest, like `scores.mean <- example.data$score_mean`?

Comment: You mean something like `lapply( 1:nrow(df) , function(i) rnorm( 3 , df[i,'mean'] , sd=df[i,'sd'] ) )`? (`df` is `example.data`). To use the mean and sd at random you could replace `1:nrow(df)` in the first argument of `lapply` with `sample( 1:nrow(df) , n , TRUE )` to use random rows (with replacement).

Comment: p.s. in your example it would suffice to turn `results.list` into a `data.frame` with `as.data.frame( results.list )`!! (a `data.frame` is in essence a list based structure itself).

Comment: I've used `Rcpp` for simulations over large `n` and if your function is straightforward enough, easy to write and speed up is significant.

Comment: Ooh. Using @SimonO'Hanlon's `lapply(...)` function is a huge improvement. My method takes 97.7 seconds to run on my actual data (1000 columns); Simon's takes 7.8 seconds. Super impressive. `Rcpp` could probably speed it up more, but that requires learning C++ :)

Comment: What about if you use `replicate`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik `replicate` is just an `lapply` wrapper.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik of course, you can just use `rnorm` by itself (it was late last night when I was looking at this!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is to take advantage of the vectorisation built-in to `rnorm`. Both the `mean` and `sd` arguments are vectorised, however you can only supply a single integer for the number of draws. If you supply a vector to the `mean` and `sd` arguments, R will cycle through them until it has completed the required number of draws. Therefore, just make the argument `n` to `rnorm` a multiple of the length of your `mean` vector. The multiplier will be the number of replicates for each row of your data.frame. In the function below this is `n`.

I can't think of a factor way than using `base::rnorm` on its own.

#### Worked example

---

```
#example data
df <- data.frame(country=c("a", "b", "c"), 
                           mean=c(1, 10, 100), 
                           sd=c(1, 2, 10))

#function which returns a matrix, and takes column vectors as arguments for mean and sd
normv <- function( n , mean , sd ){
    out <- rnorm( n*length(mean) , mean = mean , sd = sd )
    return( matrix( out , , ncol = n , byrow = FALSE ) )
    }

#reproducible result (note order of magnitude of rows and input sample data)
set.seed(1)
normv( 5 , df$mean , df$sd )
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
#[1,]  0.3735462  2.595281   1.487429   0.6946116   0.3787594
#[2,] 10.3672866 10.659016  11.476649  13.0235623   5.5706002
#[3,] 91.6437139 91.795316 105.757814 103.8984324 111.2493092
```

Comment: Oh, fantastic! I had no idea the `n` argument in `rnorm()` could take a vector. This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very quickly if you remember that rnorm(1, mean, sd) is the same as rnorm(1)*sd + mean so using your data frame df, you can generate sim simulations of your obs observations like:

```
obs = nrow(df)
sim = 1000
mat = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(obs*sim), obs, sim) * df$sd + df$mean)
```

You can check that this has the desired means by using rowMeans(mat) and check the standard deviation for, say, row 1 as sd(mat[1,]).